# RESORUCE NOT FOUND ERROR: o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet : POST "/live/api/auth/login", parameters={} where NGINX routes live/api to SpringBoot API

Tags: java, spring-boot, api, nginx, nginx-reverse-proxy

I am trying to serve SpringBoot API(:8081) using an NGINX reverse proxy as below.

```
   location /live/api {
       proxy_pass http://localhost:8081;

      proxy_set_header    Host               $host;
      proxy_set_header    X-Real-IP          $remote_addr;
      proxy_set_header    X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
      proxy_set_header    X-Forwarded-Host   $host;
      proxy_set_header    X-Forwarded-Server $host;
      proxy_set_header    X-Forwarded-Port   $server_port;
      proxy_set_header    X-Forwarded-Proto  $scheme;

    }
```

This NGINX configuration is working but the SpringBoot API does not take `/live/api` as its base. Below is `SecurityConfig.java`.

```
    // Set permissions on endpoints
    http.authorizeRequests()
            // Our public endpoints
            .antMatchers("/auth/**").permitAll()
            .antMatchers("/public/**").permitAll()

            // Our private endpoints
            .anyRequest().authenticated();
```

Example situations:

1. POST "/live/api/auth/login", parameters={} `RESOURCE NOT FOUND ERROR`

```
o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : POST "/live/api/auth/login", parameters={}
o.s.w.s.handler.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping  : Mapped to ResourceHttpRequestHandler [Classpath [META-INF/resources/],
 Classpath [resources/], Classpath [static/], Classpath [public/], ServletContext [/]]
o.j.s.OpenEntityManagerInViewInterceptor : Opening JPA EntityManager in OpenEntityManagerInViewInterceptor
o.s.w.s.r.ResourceHttpRequestHandler     : Resource not found
o.j.s.OpenEntityManagerInViewInterceptor : Closing JPA EntityManager in OpenEntityManagerInViewInterceptor
o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Completed 404 NOT_FOUND
o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : "ERROR" dispatch for POST "/error", parameters={}
s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : Mapped to org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.servlet.error.BasicErrorController#error(HttpServletRequest)
o.j.s.OpenEntityManagerInViewInterceptor : Opening JPA EntityManager in OpenEntityManagerInViewInterceptor
o.s.w.s.m.m.a.HttpEntityMethodProcessor  : Using 'application/json', given [application/json] and 
supported [application/json, application/*+json,
 application/json, application/*+json]
o.s.w.s.m.m.a.HttpEntityMethodProcessor  : Writing [{timestamp=Mon Jul 12 16:32:01 UTC 2021, status=404, error=Not Found, 
message=, path=/live/api/auth/ (truncated)...]
o.j.s.OpenEntityManagerInViewInterceptor : Closing JPA EntityManager in OpenEntityManagerInViewInterceptor
o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Exiting from "ERROR" dispatch, status 404
o.a.c.c.C.[.[.[/].[dispatcherServlet]    : Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] 
in context with path [] threw exception
```

Comment: `/live/api` is protected, hence it will redirect to login (that is what you configured in your security config).

Answer (score 0):

Just add `server.servlet.contextPath=/live/api` to your application config file.